# How to keep same uuid in two separate dataframes?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, uuid

There is one input dataframe `df`(with 10 columns, col1-col10) in which I am adding a new column `uuid` by using below UDF and transform into another dataframe `newdf`.

Next, from `newdf` datafame, I am creating two separate dataframes `df1`(uuid,col1-col5) and `df2`(uuid,col6-col10) with mentioned columns only.

The problem arises here, I want the `uuid` column should be the same and unique for a row in both `df1` & `df2` dataframes.

Since Spark work with lazy evaluation, it runs UDF when I write `df1` and `df2` due to which it is giving different `uuid` value for each row in both `df1` and `df2` dataframes.

**Solution** that I follow as of now that, I am writing `newdf` dataframe first at temp path and reading it back. But this logic is not good for a large volume of data.

Below is a code snippet:

```scala
df.show(false)
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 | col9 | col10 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+
| A1   | A2   | A3   | A4   | A5   | A6   | A7   | A8   | A9   |  A10  |
| B1   | B2   | B3   | B4   | B5   | B6   | B7   | B8   | B9   |  B10  |
| C1   | C2   | C3   | C4   | C5   | C6   | C7   | C8   | C9   |  C10  |
+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+------+------+
  
val uuid = udf(() => java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString)
val newdf = df.withColumn("uuid", uuid())

val df1 = newdf.select(uuid, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
val df2 = newdf.select(uuid, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10)

df1.write.format("parquet").save("/df1/")
df2.write.format("parquet").save("/df2/")

df1.show()
+-----------------+------+------+------+------+------+
|     uuid        | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
+-----------------+------+------+------+------+------+
|1abdecf-8303-4a4e| A1   | A2   | A3   | A4   | A5   |
|1dbcecf-1304-4a4e| B1   | B2   | B3   | B4   | B5   |
|1vbdecf-8406-4a4e| C1   | C2   | C3   | C4   | C5   |
+-----------------+------+------+------+------+------+

df2.show()
+-----------------+------+------+------+------+------+
|     uuid        | col6 | col7 | col8 | col9 | col10|
+-----------------+------+------+------+------+------+
|2aodecf-3303-6n5e| A6   | A7   | A8   | A9   | A10  |
|2docecf-6305-6n5e| B6   | B7   | B8   | B9   | B10  |
|2vodecf-1406-6n5e| C6   | C7   | C8   | C9   | C10  |
+-----------------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

**Expected Output:** Same **uuid** in both dataframes across row

```scala
df1.show()
+-----------------+------+------+------+------+------+
|     uuid        | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
+-----------------+------+------+------+------+------+
|1abdecf-8303-4a4e| A1   | A2   | A3   | A4   | A5   |
|1dbcecf-1304-4a4e| B1   | B2   | B3   | B4   | B5   |
|1vbdecf-8406-4a4e| C1   | C2   | C3   | C4   | C5   |
+-----------------+------+------+------+------+------+

df2.show()
+-----------------+------+------+------+------+------+
|     uuid        | col6 | col7 | col8 | col9 | col10|
+-----------------+------+------+------+------+------+
|1abdecf-8303-4a4e| A6   | A7   | A8   | A9   | A10  |
|1dbcecf-1304-4a4e| B6   | B7   | B8   | B9   | B10  |
|1vbdecf-8406-4a4e| C6   | C7   | C8   | C9   | C10  |
+-----------------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Please provide best possible way to overcome this problem.

Comment: How big is newdf? Can you `cache()` it?

Comment: cache I had tried and it also worked with small data but my data will increase exponentially with time so can't use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

> solution is in spark scala api

**Use `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes` as udf**

### Load the test data provided

```scala
df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
      * |col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10|
      * +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
      * |A1  |A2  |A3  |A4  |A5  |A6  |A7  |A8  |A9  |A10  |
      * |B1  |B2  |B3  |B4  |B5  |B6  |B7  |B8  |B9  |B10  |
      * |C1  |C2  |C3  |C4  |C5  |C6  |C7  |C8  |C9  |C10  |
      * +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- col5: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- col6: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- col7: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- col8: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- col9: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- col10: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### create same UUID

```scala
    val uuid = udf((s: String) => UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).toString)
    val newdf = df.withColumn("uuid", uuid(concat_ws(":", df.columns.map(col): _*)))

    val df1 = newdf.select("uuid", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")
    val df2 = newdf.select("uuid", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "col10")
    df1.show(false)
    /**
      * +------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
      * |uuid                                |col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
      * +------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
      * |0c26ece0-708a-3105-896f-e70d18b67766|A1  |A2  |A3  |A4  |A5  |
      * |0e19058c-3c14-3d2f-8c71-b7308f63b0d6|B1  |B2  |B3  |B4  |B5  |
      * |eef9969b-3650-31f5-b877-d5e86ce7b1b7|C1  |C2  |C3  |C4  |C5  |
      * +------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
      */

    df2.show(false)
    /**
      * +------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+-----+
      * |uuid                                |col6|col7|col8|col9|col10|
      * +------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+-----+
      * |0c26ece0-708a-3105-896f-e70d18b67766|A6  |A7  |A8  |A9  |A10  |
      * |0e19058c-3c14-3d2f-8c71-b7308f63b0d6|B6  |B7  |B8  |B9  |B10  |
      * |eef9969b-3650-31f5-b877-d5e86ce7b1b7|C6  |C7  |C8  |C9  |C10  |
      * +------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+-----+
      */
```

Comment: what if same values occur?

Comment: "Same values occur" for what?

Comment: columns, squire, what else could I mean generating same value? issue or not?

Comment: This won't break "Same uuid in both dataframes across row" requirement. Do you see any problems?

Comment: just asking, row m & n are different

Comment: @SomeshwarKale Thanks for the reply, just have one concern, what if there is no primary column and two rows have exactly same data? then will it give unique uuid for rows?

Comment: yes, it will. Please consider adding row_number then if no primary key